# Asp.Net 5 (vNext) - How to implement custom password verification etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm prototyping a web application using ASP.NET 5. The template project Visual Studio 2015 creates is useful, but it uses Entity Framework which I don't want to use. I already have my own logic for verifying passwords to login, create new users etc. using ADO.NET.

For example, the template project uses functions like `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, rememberMe, false);`, but I want to implement my own code for doing this, I'm not sure where I can override this behaviour.

I suspect the config code in the Startup class needs to be changed, this code for example:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Looks like it is setting up the identity logic to use the EF, I imagine I need to implement my own versions of IUserStore and other interfaces, but I'm not sure where to start and I can't find any examples of how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First rule of security DO NOT CREATE YOUR OWN SECURITY.

Do NOT write your own PASSWORD VERIFICATION.

Now that's out of the way.

You are allowed to write your own Identity Store.

[Check out the official tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

The basic premise is that you Implement your own `IUser<T>` and a `IUserStore<IUser<T>>` that allows the .net identity provider to access your storage. However at the end of the day...there should be a `ADO.Net Identity Store`.

Comment: Yes I definitely don't want to re-invent the wheel on the security model, I hadn't found the link you gave, it looks useful, but it is be for Identity 2.0, I believe ASP.NET 5 uses a newer version, I wonder how similar they are? Thanks.